# "A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource" during AWS Glacier restore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-glacier

I'm encountering the above message when attempting to restore (thaw) objects from an AWS bucket that have a storage class of Glacier Flexible Retrieval. The code (proprietary so can't be shared in full) that's initiating is:

```
response = client.restore_object(Bucket=<bucket-name>, Key=<obj>,
    RestoreRequest={'Days':3, 'GlacierJobParameters': {'Tier': "Standard"}})
```

Very occasionally I get the following failure:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (OperationAborted) when calling the
    RestoreObject operation: A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress
    against this resource. Please try again.
```

I've seen this error associated with creation/deletion/recreation of buckets - including on SO - but not with thawing data from AWS Glacier in this way and there's no real obvious solution other than try again/keep trying. The problem with that approach is that when I've got this, I find it seems to happen again and again without any real obvious reason - and then just disappears. So how many times do I need to try? How long between tries?

The [AWS Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/restore_object.html) doesn't mention this error at all as far as I can tell.

Ideally I just want to know what's caused the issue so I can avoid it in the first place. Can anyone advise what the reason might be for the error appearing? The bucket has not been changed (ie. deleted/created) so it seems more related to the object but I can't see how that would have changed either.